# How to get the name of a class without the package?

Tags: java

In C# we have `Type.FullName` and `Type.Name` for getting the name of a type (class in this case) with or without the namespace (package in java-world).

What is the java equivalent to `Type.Name`?

Clearly there must be a better way than using `Class.getName()` and strip it of the package name manually.

Comment: I did a quick search on this and was not to impressed by the first results that I found on Google so consider this as a freebie.

Comment: Forget Google!  The **first place to look** for answers about the Java standard class library are the Java API docs (aka javadocs): http://java.sun.com/javase/reference/api.jsp

Comment: For literal answers to the question, see: [How to *really* get the name of a class without the package](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20583164/2402790).

Answer (score 463, accepted):

[`Class.getSimpleName()`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getSimpleName%28%29)

> Returns the simple name of the underlying class as given in the source code. Returns an empty string if the underlying class is anonymous.
>
> The simple name of an array is the simple name of the component type with "[]" appended. In particular the simple name of an array whose component type is anonymous is "[]".

It is actually stripping the package information from the name, but this is hidden from you.

Comment: It also maps the internal name of an anonymous class to an empty String and does stuff with array class names.

Comment: I didn't know it could return an empty string, and IMHO that's a design flaw.  If there is no simple name it should throw an exception.

Comment: For inner classes, it strips not only the package but also the outer class' name. (I wanted the other behaviour, so this answer is wrong for me.)

Comment: @toolforger Would `this.getClass.getEnclosingClass.getSimpleName + "$" + this.getClass.getSimpleName` work for your purpose?

Comment: @AlonsodelArte Not sure (there are complications like multiple nesting levels and anonymous classes). Not too relevant anyway, I just wanted to point out that the answer is technically incorrect for the question as written.

Comment: @toolforger Yeah, probably not. For my purpose that prompted me to look this up, `getSimpleName()` does just fine.

Answer (score 18):

If using a StackTraceElement, use:

```
String fullClassName = stackTraceElement.getClassName();
String simpleClassName = fullClassName.substring(fullClassName.lastIndexOf('.') + 1);

System.out.println(simpleClassName);
```

Comment: The question is about the situation where you have the class object, not a stack trace.